# uline and uuline same line width

Tags: ulem

How to align uline and uuline same width of line using ulem package?
I attached screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `\uline` uses a precisely controlled "rule" for the underline, but `\uuline` lays down the double rule in chunks because it is written the way `\uwave` is (using `\markoverwith`). The chunks are clearly a requirement for `\uwave` (the squiggle characters have to align, and they only come in whole characters), whereas `\uuline` uses chunks more for convenience.

How critical is it that they line up? The definition of `\uuline` could use a smaller "chunk" to give more precise matching of size. It could be made to match exactly using two rules, but that would require rewriting more internal macros.

A `\uuline` with smaller chunks can be defined like this:

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\uuline{\leavevmode \bgroup
 \UL@setULdepth
 \ifx\UL@on\UL@onin \advance\ULdepth2.8\p@\fi
 \let\ULleaders\cleaders % added
 % use \UL@pixel widths below
 \markoverwith{\lower\ULdepth\hbox{\kern-0.5\UL@pixel
    \vbox{\hrule width3\UL@pixel\kern1\p@\hrule}\kern-0.5\UL@pixel}}%
 \ULon}
```

That may well be good enough.